# iOS button is clickable but not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, qr-code

I have a view(let's call it scanView) that opens camera to scan for QR Codes. I have placed a button on it which opens or closes the flash. The problem i am facing is that the button is getting clicked but it is not visible, i,e, I can turn flash on or off by clicking on screen where i placed the button, but the button is not visible. I checked the Alpha of button, tried bringing subview to front also. Nothing works. Is it some issue related to QR reader of iOS?
Here is the implementation of QR Reader:

```
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = scanView.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        scanView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        captureSession.startRunning()
```

[image: view heirarchy debugger image]

As you can see above I have added a background color and background image too for clarity. According to me the button looks fine in hierarchy.
On this scanView, I am adding the button from my xib file

Comment: Check your button width and height along with title and bg image if there is any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not related to QR Reader implementation probably.

Second, ask yourself how the button is supposed to be seen? Title? Image?

Third, you can always press 'Debug View Hierarchy' button while running the app, to stop its execution and to see all the views present on the screen.

'Debug View Hierarchy' button in on the same Debug Tools pane below where other debugging tools (like breakpoints) are placed.

Comment: Hi @rommex. Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Please see the heirarchy image above in my edited question. Also the button is an image and has nothing to do with it being a picture that is transparent because i have tried with different images

Comment: @Shubham1212 Is ‘hidden’ property unckecked? What is the frame values fir the button?

Comment: yes the hidden property is unchecked. Frame values for button are: X:310, Y:20, Width: 50, Height: 50

Comment: i managed to solve the issue by setting the zposition of button programmatically

Comment: @Shubham1212 but what was the reason for the button to stay below other views? And how could it be tapped still?

Comment: i couldn't exactly figure it out. But according to me, the button was there but z position set it's visibility. I selected max for zposition value so that the user can see it. I found it in apple's documentation

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use `Debug View Hierarchy`, so you can clearly see where the button is on the screen and why it's not visible.

I think you have a problem with the image of the button because you are able to click on the button but are not able to see it, make sure the image is added properly on to the button.

Keep one thing in mind, that if it is clickable, then it is there, focus on its presentation. Also try to add a background color to it and remove the image, just to make sure your other implementation is working properly.

Comment: Hi @rana5ohaib. Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Please see the heirarchy image above in my edited question

Comment: The layer that is selected in that image, is that your button?
The hierarchy does show that it's on top and is visible, I'm wondering what can make it not be visible on your device.
Is it still not visible? ... can you share a screen shot of the device as well?

Comment: i managed to solve the issue by setting the zposition of button programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by setting the zposition of the button. Thank you for your time everyone